# Fat Free Framework - Flash Messages Cleared By Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, fat-free-framework

Has anybody figured out a way to maintain the $_SESSION variable on a redirect, when using Fat Free Framework? Currently, anytime I use a redirect, my Flash Messages get cleared and will not display.

For instance, in the following code, neither message displays:

```
if ($verifyUser) {
    $this->createUserSession($verifyUser);
    if ($_SESSION['user_premium'] == 2) {
        // Admin, so go to admin dashboard
        $this->flash->addMessage('You\'re logged in as Administrator.', 'success');
        $this->f3->reroute('/admin/index');
    } else {
        // Regular user, so go to regular dashboard
        $this->flash->addMessage('You\'re logged in as a registered user.', 'success');
        $this->f3->reroute('/dashboard/index');
    }
}
```

Flash messaging works perfectly when redrawing a page (when validating forms, for instance), but anytime I reroute, the session variable seems to get cleared.

Any thoughts are gratefully accepted.

Comment: How does your flash object work?

Comment: Hey, do you still have problem with this? I suspect that you have something below those code that triggers the flash messages to be viewed (which can clear that up). I reccomend you to add `return` keyword whenever you do reroute so the code execution will be stoped right there.

Comment: Honestly, I can't remember how I addressed this ultimately. I just know that I got it working, somehow, and moved on. Some day I'll circle back around to that project (a personal one) because I have some new ideas for it, and I'm sure I'll have to revisit it. :)